# Buttons in table cell can't be pressed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I'm using Java Swing to make a table with buttons I can use to be actions based on the row.

I am using a custom cell renderer to try rendering multiple buttons in a table cell. I have managed to cobble together something that does what I want visually but the buttons don't actually function. They simply don't fire and don't react visually to clicks or mouse overs. Looking for a way to make the buttons react and actually fire their actions.

Cell renderer class:

```java
public class ButtonsCell extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {
    JPanel panel;

    public ButtonsCell() {
        this.updateData(Collections.emptyList());
    }

    private void updateData(List<JButton> buttons) {
        this.panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));


        for(JButton button : buttons) {
            button.setMargin(new Insets(-2, 0, -2, 0));

            this.panel.add(button);
        }
    }

    private void updateData(List<JButton> buttons, boolean isSelected, JTable table) {
        this.updateData(buttons);

        if (isSelected) {
            this.panel.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        }else{
            this.panel.setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                 boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        this.updateData((List<JButton>)value, isSelected, table);
        return panel;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return null;
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                   boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        this.updateData((List<JButton>)value, isSelected, table);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Visually, this produces:

[image]

Comment: `this.updateData((List<JButton>)value, isSelected, table);` my first thought is, buttons (or any other components) shouldn't be part of your model

Comment: But I want it to hold said buttons, I designed the renderer to do so. There is a guide here to do so, along with have other elements: https://www.pekalicious.com/blog/custom-jpanel-cell-with-jbuttons-in-jtable/

Comment: Components don't belong in the model, data belongs in the model.  The renderer/editor then decides how that data should be presented to the user - no offence, but this is a pretty basic concept used in most languages.  Even your guide doesn't do that - it takes the "data" from the model and then presents in a manner which it feels is appropriate

Comment: This design is appropriate (well, necessary) for web UIs, but in a desktop application, there are better ways to accomplish this.  Considering having just one `E` button and one `D` button, located outside of the JTable, which when pressed act on whichever rows of the table are selected.

Comment: Sometimes a table with buttons in it is just the right way to go. The problem we encounter is the Swing magic used to paint and edit `JTable` cells. For a hint at getting clicks to work, take a look at the source to `DefaultCellEditor` and see how the component determines if it should handle the mouse click. Checkboxes and combo boxes are used all the time in JTables and they both need this activate-on-single-click behavior.